# How to show a string in a tooltip slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to show the months names on the tooldtip not the numbers, I am doing:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row" id="time" >
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    Days: <b>1</b> <input id="days" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="31" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,31]"/> <b>31</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    Months: <b>January</b> <input id="months" type="text"
          data-provide="slider"
          data-slider-ticks-labels='["January", "February", "March, "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]'
          data-slider-min="1"
          data-slider-max="12"
          data-slider-step="1"
          data-slider-value=""
          data-slider-tooltip="show" /> <b>December</b>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    Years: <b>0</b> <input id="years" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="2017" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[0,2017]"/> <b>Today</b>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And I call it:

```
$("#days, #years, #months").slider({
  tooltip: 'always'
});
```

The slider works fine but the tooltip isn't showing the months names but the numbers.

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1308/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you'll have to use the formatter function. You can see the example  here (Example 23).

In your case:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

$("#days, #years").slider({
    tooltip: 'always'
});

$("#months").slider({
    tooltip: 'always',
    value: [0, 12],
    tooltip: 'always',
    formatter: function(values) {
         return months[values[0]-1] + ' : ' + months[values[1]-1];
    },
});
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1qcqLadd/

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot. One last question tho, if i wanted to have a range for the months how would I treat that? Days and Years are a range for example

Comment: Just edit your #months slider by adding 'value' and edit the 'formatter' like i edited above